# TCPDF Trouble - Double Coding

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to build a PDF output in CakePhp using TCPDF, I've got it working and rendering the PDF correctly etc, but something strange is happening.

It's producing a broken PDF unless I call the Output function twice.

Any ideas? or alternatives?

```
$this->pdf->core->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
$this->pdf->core->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: How did you discover that this made it work? (Out of curiosity).

Comment: is is a real strange behavior, sadly the configurations at the beginnning after creating the object, wont have any affect on the result. but thanks for mentioning it, without you I'd probably shout against the wall!

Answer (score 0):

Find your solution here.. 
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2754
may be some issue related your configuration

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with DOMPDF in the end anyways, that works loads better.